# Json to csv dynamic columns javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a array of objects and i need to convert to a csv, but those objects has dynamics keys, i already create my csv columns using the object with the greater amount of keys ,now i need that if a row doesnt have the atribute the column must be empty.

My current aproach:

```
let output =  [{

    "De 0 a 10, qual a chance de você RECOMENDAR o Compass?": "7",
    "De 0 a 10, que nota atribui à QUALIDADE do Compass": "8",
    "Alguns destes itens já apresentou defeito?": "Painel do Motorista.",
    "Pergunta teste insertção dinâmica": "Painel do Motorista"
},

{
    "De 0 a 10, qual a chance de você RECOMENDAR o Compass?": "7",
    "De 0 a 10, que nota atribui à QUALIDADE do Compass": "8",
    "Test Question":"foo",
    "Alguns destes itens já apresentou defeito?": "Painel do Motorista.",
    "Test 2 Question":"bar",
    "Pergunta teste insertção dinâmica": "Painel do Motorista",


}]

  let key = 0;
      let max = 0;
      output.forEach(function(v, k) {
        if (max < +Object.keys(v).length) {
          max = +Object.keys(v).length;
          key = k;
        }
      });

      let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
      csvContent += [
        Object.keys(output[key]).join(";"),
        ...output.map(item => {
          console.log(item)
          console.log( Object.values(item).join(";"))
          ;
        })
      ]
        .join("\n")
        .replace(/(^\[)|(\]$)/gm, "");

      const csv = encodeURI(csvContent);
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("href", csv);
      link.setAttribute("download", "export.csv");
      link.click();
    },
```

Current CSV output:

```
De 0 a 10 qual a chance de você RECOMENDAR o Compass?,De 0 a 10 que nota atribui à QUALIDADE do Compass,Test Question,Alguns destes itens já apresentou defeito?,Test 2 Question,Pergunta teste insertção dinâmica

7,8,Painel do Motorista,Painel do Motorista,Painel do Motorista,Painel do Motorista
5,5,foo,Painel do Motorista,bar,Painel do Motorista
```

Desired CSV output (if object doesnt have property the column must be empty):

```
De 0 a 10 qual a chance de você RECOMENDAR o Compass?,De 0 a 10 que nota atribui à QUALIDADE do Compass,Test Question,Alguns destes itens já apresentou defeito?,Test 2 Question,Pergunta teste inserção dinâmica.

7,8,,Painel do Motorista,,Painel do Motorista
5,5,foo,Painel do Motorista,bar,Painel do Motorista
```

Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your function:

```
console.log( Object.values(item).join(";"))
```

you just join all the existing values of item. Try to map it with keys:

```
console.log(Object.keys(output[key]).map(it => item[it] || '').join(";"))
```

This will iterate through existing composed headers for the csv, retrieve value if exist and add empty string otherwise
Also do not forget return valu from `...output.map():` currently it contains only console.log operations

```
let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
      csvContent += [
        Object.keys(output[key]).join(";"),
        ...output.map(item => {
          return Object.keys(output[key]).map(it => item[it] || '').join(";");
        })
      ]
        .join("\n")
        .replace(/(^\[)|(\]$)/gm, "");
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, didn't work out my csv is empty only headers column

Comment: because in `...output.map` you only log elements to console. after both console.log add smth like `return Object.keys(output[key]).map(it => item[it] || '').join(";")`